# Domain join account password change - issues?

Tags: dns, active-directory

There is a MS Active Directory. There are several computers that used the domain_join account to join the domain. Now I need to change the password of domain_join account. I have tested using a test machine and a domain_join_test account and nothing changed, the machine stayed in the domain and I was able to log in using my domain account and password (not domain_join_test). I went through various articles and my understanding is the password used to join the domain is not saved.  It is only needed to authenticate to AD to make sure you have the permission to add the machine to the domain (e.g. for a different thing but the domain part explains my test https://community.netapp.com/t5/ONTAP-Discussions/Domain-Join-with-Admin-Account-change-Password/m-p/433207). However I cannot find any documentation on this.

So the question is, does changing the password of the account (on AD) used for joining computers to the domain will have any effect on the computers already in the domain? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. As per [Understanding Computer Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731641(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) every computer that joins a domain has a computer account which is similar to a user account with its user name and password. When a domain_join account is used to join the computer to the domain, a new computer account is created with its password. And the  computer (machine) account's password change is initiated by the computer every 30 days by default ([Machine Account Password Process](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/machine-account-password-process/ba-p/396026)). Therefore, changing the password of the account that was used to join the computer to the domain will not affect the computer that is in the domain already.